# AppSource validation failed due to the word Excel being in the title

Tags: office-store

We are in the process of publishing our Excel add-in into Microsoft AppSource. However, the validation failed due to the word Excel being in the title. Please see the certReport we received:

> **General Content**
>
> **1100.1.1.2 Title Uses Microsoft IP**
>
> Your title may not include Microsoft product names e.g. Excel.
>
> Please update the title and re-submit your offer.

Both our submission title and the title displayed in the add-in UI contain the word Excel (i.e. 'xxx for Excel').
Could you confirm that changing the submission title is all that is required, not the add-in UI title?

Comment: Well, do it and tell us ?

Comment: Note that anything but programming-questions is off-topic on this site, especially this is NOT a microsoft support site.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution